# React-vis x- axis shows .5 numbers

Tags: reactjs, react-vis

I feel the answer is so obvious and simple but I can't find it.

Im visualizing a lineSeries chart with react-vis. My x data is 1,2,3,4,5 and so on. Y are kilograms.
But the x-axis rendert shows not only 1,2,3,4 ... but shows it 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 plus extra numbers (al the halfs, 0.5, 1.5...etc) I don't know how to solve this and get it to just show the numbers given.

Code I use is this:

```
<XYPlot
 height={300}
 width={800}
 yDomain={[70,110]}>
  <LineSeries
   data={plotArray}
   color="#2c2c2c"
   opacity={1}
   style={{ fill: 'none'}}
  />
  <XAxis />
  <YAxis />
</XYPlot>
```

EDIT: i found this which make the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 but on the x- axis it still shows the .5 lines. like this.

[example x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzrtL.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/issues/957) help?

Comment: Hi ignacio, thanks for your help but it doesn't work. now it puts just "1" on the x-axis.

Comment: hi Ignacio, somehow, this helped me:
<XAxis
               
                tickFormat={val => Math.round(val) === val ? val : ""}
                />